# Cannot load storage module 'Database'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried storing the images in database using paperclip and it displays an error.

Comment: provide code + exact error msg

Comment: you gave a link https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3 i tried and the url is not expiring

Comment: so you should file a bug on paperclip since it's their own documentation

Comment: then i tried this. Instead of using s3 i tried database as storage. This is the link from which i tried http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/5/29/paperclip-sample-app-part-3-saving-file-attachments-in-a-database-blob-column but when i use :storage => :database then it displays "Cannot load storage module 'Database'"

Comment: Paperclip doesn't provide option to store in database

Comment: but the link http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/5/29/paperclip-sample-app-part-3-saving-file-attachments-in-a-database-blob-column has shown

Comment: read the date of the post + refer to official doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no storage in database with paperclip, [see doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage).

Comment: yes i saw. Ok then is there is any other way that i can make the image restricted to users alone

Comment: if you expose an url to people, it cannot, by definition, be private (wherever you store the file). Expirable url an alternative

Comment: as said earlier, file an issue on the github's gem page.

Comment: ok. And one more thing, how can i put the questions specifically to you or is there is any chat room where i can post the questions?

Comment: there is a rails chat room (with few people), or a chat room is automatically created when too many comments are posted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16040/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-usr)

Comment: No i was not asking that. what can i do if i want to post my questions to you? Because at times i find nobody responding for few questions.

Comment: :) open source relies on people sharing knowledge for free, sometimes you find the good person at the good moment, sometimes not. I'm ready to ask questions when I browse stackoverflow, it's random for sure but I won't receive questions by mail or alike unless I work as consultant

Comment: btw, technically, I answered your question